# Number of Different Elements of $S_{ijkl}$ with Some Symmetries

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, tensors

I am not good at combinatorics so I am asking this simple question to learn a little. In fact, this question is motivated by the symmetries happening for the stiffness and Eshelby tensors in the theory of elasticity.

Suppose that we have an array whose elements are denoted by $S_{ijkl}$ where the indicices $i,j,k,l=1,2,3$.

$1.$ If we have the two kind of symmetries

$$S_{ijkl}=S_{jikl} \\
S_{ijkl}=S_{ijlk}$$

then what are the number of different elements of $S_{ijkl}$?

$2.$ If we have the three kind of symmetries

$$S_{ijkl}=S_{jikl} \\
S_{ijkl}=S_{ijlk} \\
S_{ijkl}=S_{klij}$$

then what are the number of different elements of $S_{ijkl}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you can consider the sets $\{i,j\}$ and $\{k,l\}$ as your indeces. Hence, for each pair you have 6 combinations $11,22,33, 12,13,23$ and therefore total of $36$ independent components.

In the second case, the third condition implies that $6$ by $6$ matrix from the case 1 is symmetric which gives you $21$ independent components.

Comment: (+1), Thanks for the answer but I prefer to forget about matrices in the second case. Can you kindly tell me how to solve the second case with the notions you used for the first case? :)

Comment: The first 2  conditions are the same, so you have 36 pairs of indices $(11,11), (11,22), \ldots (23, 23)$. What the last condition tells you is that you can swap pairs of indices  therefore index $(12, 23)$ and $(23,12)$ give you the same value. You have 6 components where pairs are the same and 15 (pick two pairs from 6 possibilities) when pairs are different. That gives you 21 total

Comment: Many many thanks. :) Can you add this approach to your answer too? :)

Comment: @ H.R, or you can think of taking one element say 11 from first set it has 6 choices from other set, now think of 2nd element say 12 from first set it has 5 choices from 2nd set, since one choice 11 is no more(1112=1211). Continuing like this answer comes to 6+5+4+3+2+1.

Comment: yes, I agree. That's the other way to think about it

Comment: @rational: Why don't you write it down as an answer. It is a good kind of thinking. :)